# Having trouble using New TX font

Tags: fonts, miktex, newtx

I have been trying to use the [New TX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newtx/) font but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I have:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Page set up
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\title{Solutions to Velleman's "How to Prove It"}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
\large
Exercise 1 (a): Using the formula $2^{15}-1 = 2^{3 \cdot 5}-1$ where $a = 5, b = 3$ then $2^b-1 = 2^3-1 = 7$ and $1+2^b+2^{n\cdot b}+...+2^{(a-1)\cdot b} = 
1+2^3+2^{2\cdot3}+2^{3\cdot3}+2^{4\cdot3} = 4681$

Exercise 1 (b): $2^{32767}-1 = 2{7\cdot4681}-1$ where $b = 7$, so $x = 2^7-1 = 127$

\end{document}
```

This is what I get as an error:

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:
>
> The rtxmi source file could not be found.

and this,

> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:
>
> PK font rtxmi could not be created.

and lastly,

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file rtxmi): Font rtxmi at 864 not found 
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>
> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

If I take off this

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

then it does work. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Run updmap on a command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: `\infty` for your comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been solved by comments.